# Can't use DropShadow in Column?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I was developing a small application using QML, and i need a small drop shadow on the text component, to make it more readable, but when I add the DropShadow to the Label in the Column, it throws an error:

*"QML Column: Cannot specify top, bottom, verticalCenter, fill or centerIn anchors for items inside Column. Column will not function."*

But the text should overlap each other, here is my sample code:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    width: 100
    height: 200
    Column {
        Label {
            id: label1
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text: "First label"
        }
        DropShadow {
            anchors.fill: label1
            radius: 16
            samples: 32
            color: "#b0000000"
            source: label1
        }
        Label {
            id: label2
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text: "Second label"
        }
        DropShadow {
            anchors.fill: label2
            radius: 16
            samples: 32
            color: "#b0000000"
            source: label2
        }
    }
}
```

Did I make some mistakes? Or can't I use DropShadow inside a Column?
Should I use Item instead of Column? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues here.

The first is already explained by the error message you receive; you can't use vertical anchors in a column, and `anchors.fill: parent` implies both horizontal and vertical anchors. You can use the `width` and `height` properties instead:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    width: 100
    height: 200
    visible: true

    Column {
        Label {
            id: label1
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text: "First label"
        }
        DropShadow {
            width: label1.width
            height: label1.height
            radius: 16
            samples: 32
            color: "#b0000000"
            source: label1
        }
        Label {
            id: label2
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text: "Second label"
        }
        DropShadow {
            width: label2.width
            height: label2.height
            radius: 16
            samples: 32
            color: "#b0000000"
            source: label2
        }
    }
}
```

However, this introduces new problems:

[image]

You can see that there are duplicates of the labels. This is explained in the documentation of `DropShadow`:

> Generates a colorized and blurred shadow image of the source and places it behind the original, giving the impression that source item is raised from the background.

So, you can set `visible: false` on `label1` and `label2`.

The next issue is that the `DropShadow` will be restricted to the bounding rectangle of the `Label`. With the examples in the documentation for `DropShadow`, this is not a problem, because the bounds of the content is much smaller than the bounds of the actual item:

[image]

Since there is not much distance between the pixels making up the text and the boundary of the `Label`, you have to account for that yourself.

I doubt that this is the most elegant solution, but I'm not aware of a better one:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    id: win
    width: 150
    height: 150
    visible: true

    Item {
        width: 100
        height: 200
        Column {
            Item {
                width: label1.implicitWidth + 20
                height: label1.implicitHeight + 20
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                visible: false

                Label {
                    id: label1
                    text: "First label"
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
            DropShadow {
                width: label1.width
                height: label1.height
                radius: 4
                samples: 8
                color: "#b0000000"
                source: label1
            }
            Item {
                width: label2.implicitWidth + 20
                height: label2.implicitHeight + 20
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                visible: false

                Label {
                    id: label2
                    text: "Second label"
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
            DropShadow {
                width: label2.width
                height: label2.height
                radius: 4
                samples: 8
                color: "#b0000000"
                source: label2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Note that I also reduced the radius of the shadow to make it more noticeable.

Comment: As it is, `DropShadow` calls for "not elegant" to "ugly" solutions to apply it. IMO that's unavoidable. Thumbs up for the nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it right now, the drop shadow labels would occupy its own columns, therefore you cannot use the *anchors.fill* keyword.

Try putting the DropShadow inside the Label:

```
Label {
        id: label1
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        text: "First label"
        DropShadow {
            anchors.fill: label1
            horizontalOffset: 1
            verticalOffset: 1
            radius: 1
            samples: 3
            color: "Red"
            source: label1
        }
   }
```

better yet, put all this code in a separate file: *DropShadowText.qml*, and us it as a unique component:

```
DropShadowText{

}
```

Good luck!

Comment: It is ugly but it works with the settings you supplied - play around or remove "radius" and "samples" settings and color...and try adding horizontalOffset: 3; verticalOffset: 3 to the DropShadow

Comment: I will edit my answer with a clearer example for you.

Comment: Did you actually try the code you posted? `ShaderEffectSource: 'recursive' must be set to true when rendering recursively.`